# Junit report as PDF, preferably with Maven

Tags: maven, pdf, junit, maven-pdf-plugin

Hey all,
Looking for feedback if anyone has a good way to, when you finalize the code, run one last Junit run and create a PDF-version of the junit report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven PDF plugin with Surefire report:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/surefire-report.html

Comment: I'm trying this out, but now running into the infamous 'surefire tests that fail during site/report generation but work fine outside' problem.

Comment: How is this the answer? The link just shows the surefire report of the plugin itself and not how to generate a PDF report of your test results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://junitpdfreport.sourceforge.net

Unfortunately maven is not supported. You have to configure it with [AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Comment: Seems that the mentioned project is discontinued - does anyone know of a "more vital" project?